# Evaluate a (cubic) B-spline given coefficients & knots

Tags: interpolation, spline

I've googled like crazy, but can't figure out how to use the results (coefficients & knots) from `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline` to then evaluate points that fall between two knots. I know I could use `scipy.interpolate.splev`, but I'm trying to find pseudo code on how to evaluate a point by hand.

Ultimately, I'll be using the coeffs/knots in a Numba function, where i can break out of/jump to another evaluation loop when certain conditions are met.

For example, I've got a spline where the first 5 coefficients are:

`[0., 34.66324, 86.65809, 155.98457, 207.97942]`

and the first 5 knots (excluded the 3 padded zeros at the start) are:

`[0.,  2., 3., 4., 5.]`

From Googling, my intuition is that you transform the point which you are evaluating to the relative distance between the nearest knots and evaluate a polynomial at that transformed value. However, I couldn't back out exactly what that evaluation was based on the known results from spline function calls. I also tried digging into the scipy code, but the evaluation looks like it takes place in a compiled external file.

Comment: Have a look at the Numba discourse. https://numba.discourse.group/t/re-call-scipy-splev-routine-in-numba-jitted-function/1143 You have two options: 1) Reimplement splev in Numba (from Fortran), or 2) wrap the existing Fortran routine, to directly use it from Numba.

Answer (score 2):

A cubic spline function (i.e., with `k=3`) with a knot vector `t` and coefficient vector `c` is defined (for `t[3] <= x <= t[-4]`) as:

```
f(x) = sum(c[i] * B(x, k, i, t) for i in range(n))
```

where `n = len(t) - k - 1` and `B(x, k, i, t)` are B-Spline basis functions derived from the knot vector (called basis *elements* in the [scipy terminology here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.BSpline)).

The recursive definition of the basis functions can be found, for example, in the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.BSpline), or [this online course](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-ex-1.html), or a non-recursive implementation in Algorithm 2.2 (page 70) of [The Nurbs Book](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/The_NURBS_Book.html?id=7dqY5dyAwWkC&redir_esc=y).

Your example is a little confusing since for a cubic spline with 5 coefficients, the number of knots should be 9 (=5 + 3 + 1) and not 8. I'm not sure if this is a typo or I didn't understand correctly but assuming the number of knots matches the number of coefficients according to the formula (`len(t) = len(c) + k + 1`) , you can evaluate `f(x)` for any value `t[3] <= x <= t[-4]` using the equation above.
If you intend to use Numba (and possibly even if not) the non-recursive implementation is probably preferable.

There is also an alternative way to evaluate B-Splines, namely the [De Boor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm). You can read more about that in [this webpage](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/de-Boor.html) if you're interested.