# Absurd condition on b-spline function from scipy

Tags: python, scipy, conditional-statements, spline

I'm currently working with B-splines, who are polynomial splines. Specifically in Python with the scipy library https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html.

In the documentation, it states that the number of functions to use for create a curve, denoted as "n," should be greater than "k + 1," where "k" represents the degree. Your question is, why can't just use just "1, 2, ..., k" functions to create a curve?
B-spline's definition follows:

[B-spline definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCiLD.png)

a curve with B-splines has form like:
[B-spline curve definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9d53.png)

and code from scipy:

```
# fuctions
def B(x, k, i, t):
   if k == 0:
      return 1.0 if t[i] <= x < t[i+1] else 0.0
   if t[i+k] == t[i]:
      c1 = 0.0
   else:
      c1 = (x - t[i])/(t[i+k] - t[i]) * B(x, k-1, i, t)
   if t[i+k+1] == t[i+1]:
      c2 = 0.0
   else:
      c2 = (t[i+k+1] - x)/(t[i+k+1] - t[i+1]) * B(x, k-1, i+1, t)
   return c1 + c2
```

```
#curve
def bspline(x, t, c, k):
   n = len(t) - k - 1
   assert (n >= k+1) and (len(c) >= n)
   return sum(c[i] * B(x, k, i, t) for i in range(n))
```

scipy gives this explanation :

At least k+1 coefficients are required for a spline of degree k, so that n >= k+1. Additional coefficients, c[j] with j > n, are ignored.

BUT I DONT GET WHY THAT ASSERT N>= K+1 :(

n is defined as the number of knots t - p - 1, where p represents the degree. In my problem, I'm working with t = 5 and p = 3, so n = 5 - 3 - 1 = 1. This makes sense because I'm looking for the first degree 3 function, which is N_0,3, and it is possible to find it. However, when I try to do this with the scipy library, I encounter an error because the condition n >= k + 1 must be satisfied. But this doesn't make sense to me because it would imply that I should have 2(k + 1) knots, which would be 8, but I'm using 5

Answer (score 1):

A B-Spline basis-function `B(x)` (also called basis elements in the [scipy terminology](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.BSpline)) spans `p+1` knot intervals (e.g., from knot `t[i]` to knot `t[i+p+1]`). See for example, [this online reference](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-ex-1.html).

Therefore, in order to use `n=len(c)` functions you need the number of knots `len(t)` to be `len(t)=len(c)+p+1` for all the basis functions to be defined.
The number of basis functions (which is equal to the number of coefficients) is then `n=len(c)=len(t)-p-1` (
which is where the `n` in the code comes from).

The minimal number of B-Spline **basis-functions** that define a B-Spline curve, is `p+1`. This minimal-knot curve is just a single p-degree polynomial curve, so of course you can represent it with a single polynomial function, but this polynomial will **not be** a B-Spline basis function (it is similar to a Bezier curve that represents a single polynomial with `p+1` Bezier basis functions).

To summarize, B-Spline basis-functions require `p+1` knot intervals, which means we need `p+1` more knots than the number of basis-functions used. Since the minimal number of basis-functions used (for a single polynomial curve) is itself `p+1`, the minimal `n=len(t)-p-1` needs to be greater or equal to `p+1`, which is where the assertion comes from.

See also my answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73107767/9702190), which also has additional references.

Comment: Muchas gracias! No lo pensé de ese modo :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is to pad the knot vector. See, e.g., the source of `make_interp_spline` for several options. For the why question best take a look at the references in the BSpline docstring.

If you really need a single b-spline basis element, use `BSpline.basis_element`