# Scipy B-splines don't seem to all follow Irwin–Hall

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I'm confused how to get B-splines from Scipy. For example, if I take `t = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]` and `c=[1,0,0,0,...]` `c=[0,1,0,0,...]` `c=[0,0,1,0,...]` and `c=[0,0,0,1,...]` and call `scipy.interpolate.BSpline` then I get four lovely cubics: `x^3`, `3(x^3-2x^2+x)`, `3((1-x)^3-2(1-x)^2+(1-x)` and `(1-x)^3` but these are not the equations for B-splines in, say, [Irwin-Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution#Special_cases). Also for cubics, scipy says that 8 knots is the minimum which is a bit confusing.

If I add an extra knot, say, `t = [0.,0.,0., 0., 0.5, 1,    1,1,1]` then for `c=[0,0,0,0,1,0,....]` then that one looks like a B-spline.

So is the answer to always set coefficients to zero for what scipy calls the first and last `k` knots?

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.interpolate.BSpline` follows the B-Spline convention described for example in Unit 6 of [this online course](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/). In particular, if the first and last `k+1` knots (k=3 in your cubic case) are repeated, as in your example, the B-Spline curve is **clamped**, which means that the first and last coefficients are on the spline function (see definition [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html) for example).

I explain the number of knots `n+k+1` for n basis functions, in my answer on [Absurd condition on B-spline function from scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76350786/9702190). There I also explain why the minimal number of knots for a cubic B-Spline is 8.

A given knot vector of size `n+k+1` defines n basis functions and therefore to reconstruct the i'th (out of n) B-Spline basis function you can set the coefficient vector to 1 at the i'th entry and zero the other entries (e.g., `c=[1,0,0,0,0,0,....]` for the first basis function) as you have done in the question.

Comment: with `c=[0,1,0,0,0,...]` then I get `3(x^3-2x^2+x)` which does not seem like a valid B-spline.

Comment: It is a valid B-Spline basis function for the clamped knot vector [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]. In fact, the basis functions for this knot vector degenerate into the cubic Bezier basis functions (and indeed your result is the second Bezier basis 3(x-1)^2*x). It can be looked at as a basis function spanning the knots [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], so only one of the four knot intervals is not degenerate and so you see only a single polynomial segment in [0,1].