Fixing boundary values on a spline?
I have data x and y which are noisy evaluations of a function f:[0,alpha] -> [0,1]. I know very little about my function except that f(0) = 0 and f(alpha) = 1.
Is there any way to enforce these boundary conditions when fitting a spline?
Here is a picture, where one sees that the spline fits nicely, but the approximation is bad around 0, where it takes a value around 0.08:
I am aware of bc_type for various splines, but as far as I can tell this only allows one to specify 1st and 2nd derivative, and not fix boundary values.
(Probably this question betrays my ignorance of how splines are fitted, and that what I am asking for is not possible. I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.)
Here is a toy example:
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    ## Generate noisy evaluations of the square root function.
    ## (In my exmaple, I don't have a closed form expression for my function)

    x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
    y = np.sqrt(x) + (np.random.random(1000)-0.5)*0.05
    
    ## Fit spline
    
    spline = UnivariateSpline(x,y)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
    plt.scatter(x,y,s=1,label="Monte Carlo samples")
    plt.plot(x,spline(x),color='red',label="spline")
    plt.legend()
    plt.title("Noisy evaluations of sqrt")
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

And the resulting plot, where one sees rather nicely that the spline provides a poor approximation around zero:


There is a more general way to fit the spline, which allows the creation of a constraint on the spline's value at a specific point. (They're constraining the first derivative, but you can avoid that by removing der=1.) There may be a way to do this in the spline API, not sure.

Many thanks -- I'll try that. (I did see that answer, however thought it was only for 1st and higher derivatives.)

Can you include your existing code for this?

I added a simple example. (The function I am actually evaluating is rather complicated, and would take about 100 lines to include...)

What you're looking for is a function that constructs a clamped B-Spline that interpolates the given endpoints. Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, no scipy spline interface implements this exactly.
Still, Unit 9 of this online course describes an algorithm to solve exactly this problem denoted "Curve Global Approximation". Below I implement a python version of this algorithm, which follows the description in the website.
The function bspline_least_square_with_clamped_endpoints(x, y, n_ctrl, p) returns a scipy.interpolate.BSpline object with n_ctrl coefficients, that interpolates the first and last input points as you requested.
The x,y inputs are as in your example, and the p parameter designates the spline degree, which is 3 by default.
The parameter n_ctrl is the number of coefficients in the resulting B-Spline, which you can adjust to your needs. Note that as it increases the result may overfit.
Calling the function like below on your input, with the additional points (0,0) and (1,1) at the beginning and end, and with n_ctrl=6, results in the following figure.
spline = bspline_least_square_with_clamped_endpoints(x, y, n_ctrl=6, p=3)


The implementation follows the explanation in the website.
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline
from scipy.linalg import solve


def bspline_least_square_with_clamped_endpoints(x, y, n_ctrl, p=3):
    """
    Build a clamped BSpline least square approximation of the points (x, y) with
    number of coefficients=n_ctrl and spline_degree=p.
    The resulting BSpline will satisfy BSpline(x[0]) == y[0] and BSpline(x[-1]) == y[-1].
    Based on the algorithm presented in: https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-APP-global.html
    """

    # Build clamped knot vector between x[0] and x[-1], (simple) implementation here builds uniform inner knots
    num_inner_knots_inc_end_pts = n_ctrl - p + 1  # including knots[p] and knots[-p-1]
    inner_knots = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num_inner_knots_inc_end_pts)
    knots = np.concatenate([np.array([x[0]] * p), inner_knots, np.array([x[-1]] * p)])

    N = build_basis_functions_eval_matrix(knots, x, p)
    Q = y - N[:, 0] * y[0] - N[:, -1] * y[-1]

    # now remove first and last rows and columns since we only need rows 1 to n-1, columns 1 to h-1
    N = N[1:-1, 1:-1]
    Q = Q[1:-1]

    c = solve((N.T).dot(N), (N.T).dot(Q))
    c = np.concatenate([[y[0]], c, [y[-1]]])  # append the first and last values (as the interpolating end coefficients)

    bs = BSpline(knots, c, p)
    return bs

The current implementation constructs a clamped knot vector with inner knots uniformly spaced, there are other options (which can result in different basis functions and therefore not exactly the same resulting curve).
The main algorithmic work is done in the function build_basis_functions_eval_matrix(knots, x, p) below, which constructs the matrix N of B-Spline basis function evaluations at the inputs. The matrix shape is (len(x), n_ctrl) and the entry N[k, i] contains the evaluation of the basis function N_i(x_k).
In my implementation I use the fact that the i'th B-Spline basis functions can be reconstructed from scipy.interpolate.BSpline by setting the coefficients to [0,..,0,1,0,...,0]  - see my answer here for a discussion of how this is done.
def build_basis_functions_eval_matrix(knots, x, p=3):
    """ Build N matrix, where N[k, i] contains the evaluation of basis function N_i(x_k)."""

    n = len(knots) - p - 1  # number of ctrls == number of columns
    m = len(x)  # number of samples == number of rows

    # Using the hack that scipy.interpolate.BSpline with coefficients [0,...,0, 1, 0,...,0]
    # reconstructs the i'th basis function (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77962609/9702190).
    cols = []
    for i in range(n):
        c = np.zeros((n,))
        c[i] = 1
        N_i = BSpline(knots, c, p)
        col = N_i(x)
        cols.append(col.reshape((m, 1)))
    N = np.hstack(cols)
    return N


make_interp_spline should allow to specify "zeroth derivatives" for the values at the boundaries. That it fails now is could/should be fixed in scipy. Feel free to open an issue/send a pull request to scipy.

Of course, the comment above is about make_lsq_spline, not make_interp_spline.

Thank you, this was very helpful. @ev-br: I am very much a beginner, so have no idea how to open an issue / send a pull request. However this should not prohibit someone more knowledgeable from doing so!

One idea for fitting this function would be to say that f(0) = 0 and f(1) = 1 are just observations of your functions. Sure, they're observations that you're much more certain about than the rest, but they're still just observations.
UnivariateSpline accepts an argument, w, to give particular observations more weight. One route to "enforce" these boundary conditions would be to add these points as regular, but highly weighted points.
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
## Generate noisy evaluations of the square root function.
## (In my exmaple, I don't have a closed form expression for my function)

x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
y = np.sqrt(x) + (np.random.random(1000)-0.5)*0.05


# Add fixpoints to function
fixpoint_weight = 1000
fixpoints = np.array([
    #X, Y
    (0, 0),
    (1, 1),
]).T
x_with_fixpoints = np.concatenate([x, fixpoints[0]])
y_with_fixpoints = np.concatenate([y, fixpoints[1]])
weights = np.ones(len(x_with_fixpoints))
weights[-fixpoints.shape[1]:] = fixpoint_weight
# x must be increasing - sort x, y, and weights by x
sort_order = x_with_fixpoints.argsort()
x_with_fixpoints = x_with_fixpoints[sort_order]
y_with_fixpoints = y_with_fixpoints[sort_order]
weights = weights[sort_order]

## Fit spline
spline = UnivariateSpline(x_with_fixpoints, y_with_fixpoints, w=weights, s=0.5)

plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.scatter(x,y,s=1,label="Monte Carlo samples")
plt.plot(x,spline(x),color='red',label="spline")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Noisy evaluations of sqrt")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
print(spline(0) - 0, spline(1) - 1)



thanks a lot, this is a nice idea. (I was unaware of the 'w' parameter.) I had tried artificially adding lots of points with the same value near zero and 1, but this approach is much cleaner.

One issue with the above is that I would love a result which is guaranteed to take value 0 at 0, and 1 and alpha. (I am approximating 5000 or so such functions, and need to then solve afterwards for a fixed value between 0 and 1. Occasionally, this value is close to 0 or 1, and I want to always return a value.) In any case, I appreciate the suggestion and will probably end up using it, together with a try except clause ...

Like I said in a comment in one other answer: make_interp_spline should be able to accept zeroth derivative as a boundary value. That it does not is  a scipy enhancement request, and a fix would be welcome.
